# Wrappanel slow performance when switching itemssource

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, localization, wrappanel

Currently I am working on a project that display a list of item inside wrappanel, and each item's template will contain a TextBlock which display the item's name and a text label with localization ([using resx approach](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35159/WPF-Localization-Using-RESX-Files)).

The problem is, the list_1 is 1000 items long, it take around 1 second for first load, which is fine, however, when I switch the warppanel to load the list_2 (1000 items long) and back to list_1 for several times, it will now take 2 second to load, and after another 30 - 40 times switching, it will take 5 seconds to load the list, and each time when I switch the ItemsSource, it will take longer time to load the list.

But for the same logic, without localization, the time for loading is constant (around 1 second) for loading the list, no matter how many times you switch the ItemsSource.

Does anyone has this problem before? Please help.. Thanks!

[Sample project download link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6kqLW5TMa8VWGpZZTV1eFRubFk&usp=sharing)

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="LocalizeProject.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Grid Height="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="70">
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,34" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ItemName}" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/>
                        <Grid Height="34" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="Red" Margin="4">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="SoldoutLabel" Margin="0,8" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Resx ResxName=LocalizeProject.MultiLanguage, Key=WPF_沽清}" Foreground="White"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate1">
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
        Width="{Binding ActualWidth,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" d:DesignWidth="386" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle2" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Grid Height="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="70">
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,34" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ItemName}" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/>
                        <Grid Height="34" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="Red" Margin="4">
                            <TextBlock Margin="0,8" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding DataContext.TestString, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" Foreground="White"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate2">
        <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid d:DataContext="{d:DesignData /SampleData/MainWindowViewModelSampleData.xaml}">
    <ListView x:Name="ListViewLeft" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,50,0,80" ItemsSource="{Binding AllItemMasterList}" Width="275" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListViewItemStyle1}" ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource ItemsPanelTemplate1}" LayoutUpdated="ListViewLeft_LayoutUpdated">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <ListView x:Name="ListViewRight" Margin="287,50,228,80" ItemsSource="{Binding AllItemMasterList_1}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListViewItemStyle2}" ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource ItemsPanelTemplate1}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <Button x:Name="LeftPageUpButton" Content="List 1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="8,0,0,36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="105" Click="LeftPageUpButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="LeftPageDownButton" Content="List 2"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="117,0,0,36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="105" Click="LeftPageDownButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="RightPageUpButton" Content="List 1"  Height="40" Margin="287,0,0,36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="RightPageUpButton_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="105"/>
    <Button x:Name="RightPageDownButton" Content="List 2" Height="40" Margin="0,0,283,36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="RightPageDownButton_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="105"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="38" Margin="8,8,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="214"><Run Language="zh-tw" Text="With Localization"/></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Height="38" Margin="287,8,283,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"><Run Language="zh-tw" Text="Without Localization"/></TextBlock>
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="556,458,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="222" Text="{Resx ResxName=LocalizeProject.MultiLanguage, Key=WPF_請稍候}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: WrapPanel doesn't support UI Virtualization that is why you ended up waiting. Why do you need WrapPanel in a ListView anyway?

Comment: @devhedgehog The strange thing is that the waiting time is increasing each time after updating the itemsSource with new list, from 1 sec to 10 sec after 100 times itemsSource updates.

As I need the items showing from left to right and row by row, so use the WrapPanel as ListView's ItemsPanel